# loader exception / circular reference by decorators

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs, typeorm, reflect-metadata

### Question

I get a circular loader exception. This is may caused by the compiler option `"emitDecoratorMetadata":true`.
How can I fix it? Thanks for helpful replays!

### Introduction

I have prepared a **minimal** project for reproducing the error. Please take a look at my temporary git repository: [git repo for bug presentation](https://github.com/Kcorab/bug_presentation.git)

I use two libraries (`typeorm` and `json2typescript`) and both operate with decorators. I use multiple decorators from both libraries on some class properties.

Steps for reproducing:

1. Clone the git repo.
2. Install all packages by the command `npm i` (npm 6.9.0).
3. Open the root directory by `Visual Studio Code`.
4. Open `bugexample/test/test.spec.ts`, go to the debug view and start debugging by the config `Mocha current file`.

After these steps you should see an exception output.

```
/bugexample/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:553
                var decorated = decorator(target, propertyKey, descriptor);
                                ^
Error: Fatal error in JsonConvert. It is not allowed to explicitly pass "undefined" as second parameter in the @JsonProperty decorator.

        Class property: 
                banana

Use "Any" to allow any type. You can import this class from "json2typescript".
```

The property `banana` gets the type `Banana` as parameter and this type is `undefined` for unknown reasons. The library `json2typescript` is not the cause of this problem.

---

### Analysis

Now I want to breakdown the issue.
I begin with the two model classes and end with the test.

At first, please take a look at `bug_presentation/src/persistence/models/ape.model.ts`.

```js
import { JsonObject, JsonProperty } from "json2typescript";
import { Column, Entity, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

import { Banana } from "./banana.model";

/**
 * This is an entity class.
 * 
 * @author Tim Lehmann <l_@freenet.de>
 */
@JsonObject("Ape")
@Entity()
export class Ape {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  readonly id: number

  @JsonProperty('0')
  @Column()
  readonly name: string = null

  // the associated table holds the foreign keys

  @JsonProperty('1', Banana)
  @OneToOne(type => Banana, banana => banana.possessionOf, { cascade: true })
  readonly banana = new Banana();
}
```

In line 24 the type `Banana` is the passed parameter but for unknown reasons it's `undefined` for the current test at this time.

Now take a look at `bug_presentation/src/persistence/models/banana.model.ts`, please.

```js
import { JsonObject, JsonProperty } from "json2typescript";
import { Column, Entity, JoinColumn, OneToOne, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";

import { Ape } from "./ape.model";

/**
 * @author Tim Lehmann <l_@freenet.de>
 */
@JsonObject("Banana")
@Entity()
export class Banana {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  private readonly id: number

  @JsonProperty('0')
  @Column()
  readonly weight: string = null

  @OneToOne(type => Ape, possessionOf => possessionOf.banana)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "possessionOf" })
  readonly possessionOf: Ape = new Ape();
}
```

Line 21 and 22 are problematic. If I comment these lines out then there is no loader exception.

Please take a look at `bug_presentation/test/test.spec.ts`, lastly.

```js
import { expect } from "chai";

import { Ape } from "../src/persistence/models/ape.model";
import { Banana } from "../src/persistence/models/banana.model";

// const classApe = Ape;
const classBanana = Banana;

describe("check if class type exist", () => {

  it('check class Ape is defined', () => {
        // expect(classApe).exist;
  })

  it('check class Banana is defined', () => {
    expect(classBanana).exist;
  })
})
```

I want to test that the type/class `Banana` isn't undefined, but the test breaks earlier because the library `json2typescript` throws an exception if the passed property (in this case type `Banana`) is `undefined`.

The strange behavior is that if I assign the class `Ape` to a variable (remove the comment at line 6) then the type/class `Banana` is defined.

---

Comment: if you could summarize, at the very top, what the question / problem is, that would be helpful. I started reading but not even sure what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late on this one but I ran into a similar issue and found this post. After digging around I realized it wasn't a problem with json2typescript at all, rather a circular dependency issue.

I found this pretty useful article which helped me fix the issue in my project: https://medium.com/visual-development/how-to-fix-nasty-circular-dependency-issues-once-and-for-all-in-javascript-typescript-a04c987cf0de

Essentially, the problem is:

- In `ape.model.ts` you import banana: `import { Banana } from "./banana.model";`
- In `banana.model.ts` you import ape: `import { Ape } from "./ape.model";`

These modules are loaded in serially, so when the first gets loaded (lets pretend its `ape.model.ts`) it tries to import banana -> Banana gets loaded which tries to import ape -> ape hasn't finished being loaded so it returns undefined.

The solution the article I linked to proposes you create a `internal.ts` file for managing module loading:

```
export * from './ape.model';
export * from './banana.model';
```

then always load from internal, i.e. in `ape.model.ts`:

```
import { Banana } from './internal';
```